# How to return a domain from Odoo server action

Tags: odoo

I am trying to create a server action via the Odoo UI that will alter the domain of another field in the view. This seems to be a pretty common use-case when dealing with the Odoo source code as you can see in the following documentation:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.api.onchange

In those docs, they indicate that if I were in the source code of the model, I can define an `onchange` method and return a domain, for example, the behavior I'm trying to accomplish in the `sale.order.line` model would be:

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def _onchange_product(self):
    return {
        'domain': {'route_id': [('id', 'in', x_all_route_ids.ids)]}
    }
```

In other words, when the product of an sales order line changes, update the available options in the route_id field.

Is there any way to accomplish this same thing via a server action created through the UI? I am having trouble figuring out how to return a domain from the Python code.

The notes in the code section say:

```
# Available variables:
#  - time, datetime, dateutil, timezone: Python libraries
#  - env: Odoo Environement
#  - model: Model of the record on which the action is triggered
#  - record: Record on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise None
#  - records: Records on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise None
#  - log : log(message), function to log debug information in logging table
#  - Warning: Warning Exception to use with raise
# To return an action, assign: action = {...}
```

I don't see how I can use this to return a domain. Does anybody have any idea?

I have tried setting the python code field to simply:

```
domain = {'route_id': [('id', 'in', record.x_all_route_ids)]}
```

But that doesn't work. The route_id list is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some insight from Odoo technical support and it turns out this is possible. Anything assigned to the `action` variable will be treated as the return value for the server action.

So you can simply do:

```
action = {
    'domain': {
        'route_id': [('id', 'in', record.x_all_route_ids.ids)]
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  Only these special on-change methods return values will be evaluated correctly.

Comment: Turns out it is possible. See my answer.